# Canvas overstretches Image element, both on the same wpf grid

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas

In the image you can see in grey the Canvas element and in black the Image element. The first blue box is the first row of the grid, and second blue box is the second row of the grid.

Both the image and the canvas are in the same row, the second one. Both have width and height as auto. Yet the canvas overstretches (even going the first row) and the image stays square at the second row any one can explain why? My goal here is to have the canvas as an overlay of the image.

Thanks in advance.

[Grid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGrOy.png)

Comment: Hard to tell without taking a look at your XAML.

Comment: I built it programmatically. its part of my layout windows system, basicly the user can re-arrange add and remove "windows".

Comment: Then we'll never know what's going on in your code...

Comment: Okay, I know why the image is keeping its square aspect, its due to its stretch property being uniform. Now I want the canvas to have the same property, does any one know ?